# Nested loop in R not giving expected outputs

Tags: r, nested-loops

I wanted to use the nested loop below to work out a variable 'data' for every day within a number of years.
x is a vector of length 20 (number of years) and each of the 20 entries is the number of days the inner loop is to run for.
I also have a vector 'start' that has 20 dates in the format "1981-02-01".

I wanted to create a matrix of the output (data) that would have the data for each day in rows and then one column per year.
The code I am using below however does not seem to be updating the counters (yrcntr and daycntr) which is causing the whole thing to not work.

Also, when I try to assign values to 'data' within the loop using the counters as indices (data[daycntr yrcntr]),it's not working.

I'm not even getting an error.

I'm not sure how to write out the format of 'data' used below here, but I'll give it a go:

```
datamat=
tmax    tmin     date
11       4       "1981-03-31"
13       6       "1981-04-01"
12       7       "1981-04-02"
```

and 'start' is a vector of dates in the format: `"1981-04-02" "1981-04-03"

```
tmax<-datamat[,1]
tmin<-datamat[,2]
tdates<-datamat[,3]
yrcntr<-0;
daycntr<-0;

 for (yr in 1:length(x)){
      yrcntr<-yrcntr+1
  #find the row in the temp data that matches the startdate each year
  tempidx<- (which(tdates==start[yrcntr]))-1
  for (days in 1:numdays[yr]){
    daycntr<-daycntr+1
    dlytempidx=tempidx+1
    data[daycntr yrcntr]<- (tmax[dlytempidx]+tmin[dlytempidx])
  }
  rm(tempidx)
}
```

Comment: Can you `?dput` data in your question?

Comment: You need to define/ initialize the variable 'data' outside to body of the loop.

Comment: Do I have to define it as a certain size? Or can I just initialise it as equalling zero? Many thanks

Comment: I think there is an issue with me trying to use the daycntr and yrcntr as indices? Do you not think that could be causing an issue?

Comment: I don't understand what data[daycntr yrcntr] is suppose to mean.  Is it a matrix and you are missing a comma, or do you mean something else? It is faster if you predefine the size, but if you define it with the right dimensions it will also work.